# When should we use "Did"

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, questions, present-tense, auxiliary-verbs

I mean we only use it as an auxiliar in questions or affirmative sentences?

Could we use it with any verb in sentences?

Example:

I did jump yesterday -- I know this example is wrong but why we can't use it this way? Or with wich verbs could we use it?

Thank you very much!

PS: This is my first post. I hope I use the correct tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is grammatical in declarative sentences, but usually used only for emphasis, especially contrast, eg

> He says you didn't go and see him yesterday.
>
> I **did** go.

So *I did jump yesterday* is grammatical, but very unlikely to be said unless in response to something like

> You didn't jump yesterday.

or

> I don't think you've ever jumped.

or

> You haven't done anything all week.

(The stress would probably be different in answering the three cases: stress on *did* in the first, *yesterday* in the second, no special emphasis in the third.) The second and third could also be simply *I jumped yesterday*.